# Raspberry Pi and Arduino echo over USB

Tags: pi-3, usb, serial, arduino

I am trying to create an "echo server" with Arduino UNO, so that user could send some message to it through Raspberry Pi and receive the same response. On Pi I am using Python and PySerial library to communicate with Arduino over Usb.
Unfortunately, I cannot make it work properly, and I cannot find a decent example to guide myself. 
It would be nice, so that you could explain what am I doing wrong...
Rpi Python code:

```
import serial as ser
import io
dataIn = ser.Serial("/dev/ttyACM1", 9600)
ready = False
while True:
  if(dataIn.inWaiting() > 0):
    data = dataIn.readline()
    if(data == "R"):
      print '200 >> Arduino Ready!'
      ready = True

      while ready:
        userIn = str(raw_input('Enter Command >> '))
        ser.write(b+userIn + "\n")
    else:
      print '500 << Arduino not ready'
```

And Arduino code:

```
String content = "";
char c;
boolean sendM = false;

void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("R");
}

void loop(){
  while(Serial.available() > 0){
    c = Serial.read();
    content.concat(c);
    delay(10); 
    sendM=true;   
  }
  if(content != ""){
     Serial.println(content); 
     sendM = false;
     content = “”;
  }
}
```

Also, when I try to communicate with Arduino by using Putty I receive response from it, however, the Python code crashes without receiving any response

Comment: How do you know it crashes?  Would you care to share that information?

Comment: Yeah, sure! So when the I run the Python code, it returns message that the Arduino is unavailable although it returns ‘R’ (for ready).

Comment: That does not sound like a crash.

Comment: I have edited the code, since I was getting redundant messages from Arduino when I connect with Putty. The real problem is the control part on Rpi ...

Comment: That isn’t a crash but the message exchange is done incorrectly..

Comment: This isn't meant to be 20 questions so this will be my last comment.  You need to gather and present information.  Is data arriving at the Pi?  How do you know?  Have you got something to monitor the line?  What if anything is Python receiving?  Has all data got a newline at the end (you are using readline which won't return until a newline is received).  You need to be anticipating questions and to be supplying the information without being asked.